# Get the minimum of a name in column excel

Tags: excel

I am using Excel , I would like to get the minimum of each value in column.

Here is an example :

```
A  B

X1 2
X1 7
X2 9
X1 5
X2 1
```

I would like to have `Min of X1 = 2` and `min of X2 = 1`

I have tried this [link](https://exceljet.net/formula/minimum-value-if) but it gives me the min of the column B not the min of each value.

If someone has a better solution I will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula on the link looks like it should work if you have the named ranges set up and enter it as an array formula.

With your values in the range `A1:B5` this should work:

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$5="X1",$B$1:$B$5))
```

Remember to enter as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) - `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` and you should end up with curly brackets around the formula - `{ }`.  Not doing so will give you the minimum of `B1:B5`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of non-array versions would be,

```
=min(index(b1:b5+(a1:a5<>"X1")*1e99, , ))
=aggregate(15, 7, b1:b5/(a1:a5="X1"), 1)
```

Office 365 currently has the MINIFS function.